# How can I make moneyCounter in multi-step form if methods onClick and onChange are taken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make moneyCounter in my multi-step form. It's like buying service with a lot of options and each one of them has a different price.
I would make just:

```
state= {
    moneyCounter: 0
}
```

then:

```
onClick/onChange={this.setState({moneyCounter+6})};
```

but both of these methods are used for a different purpose.

The little sample of code of one option of this service looks like this:

```html
<div className="boosting-container">
    <span className="boosting-maintext">
        Choose your current division and tier:
    </span>
    <div className="current-division">
        <div className="division">
            <span className="rank-text">Bronze</span>
            <input 
                type="checkbox"
                className="choose_division" 
                name="currentDivision" 
                id="currentDivision" 
                value="Bronze" 
                onClick={this.toggleBronze} 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                defaultValue={valuesFormBoosting.selectMode}
            />
            {isBronze ? (
            <img src={bronzeConquest} alt="bronze" />
            ) : (
            <img src={bronzeConquestOff} alt="bronze" />
            )}
        </div>
        <div className="division">
            <span className="rank-text">Silver</span>
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                className="choose_division" 
                name="currentDivision" 
                id="currentDivision" 
                value="Silver" 
                onClick={this.toggleSilver} 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                defaultValue={valuesFormBoosting.selectMode} 
            />
            {isSilver ? (
            <img src={silverConquest} alt="silver" />
            ) : (
            <img src={silverConquestOff} alt="silver" />
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I use even props value(to assign it to the state) so I'm kinda out of options here.
Kindly please, help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Question is not clear, Please describe more and run your code in `codesandbox` like site. So, we can solve fast and easily

Comment: So to be more clear: I have multi-step form which takes care of buying service. The amount of money for service increases each step forward, depends of chosen options. My problem is: How can I do it if I actually use onClick/onChange and props 'value' for different cases. 
Small example: 
I choose Z which costs 10, then ZY which costs 5, then ZYC which costs 3 = 18. 
And thats what I want to achieve: state = { moneyCounter: 18 };